# Passing variable from a onload promise in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to pass a parameter from a onload `GET` method call to a `POST` method. The `GET` method is being loaded on `window.onload` and the `POST` function is not in the onload call otherwise the `POST` function will trigger once the window has loaded. I only want to trigger `POST` function when I click a button.

How can I pass a variable from a onload AJAX call to my `POST` function?

The only way I could think of is using a `global` variable however I don't think that's a good way of passing it to another function.

```
window.onload = function () {
    function firstCallBack() {
        $.get('http://website.com/API/docs/v1').then(function(data1){
            var passThis = "PassMeToPOST"               
        }).then(function (data2) {              
        })
    }
}
```

POST function

```
function saveSettings(passThatVar) {
    var urlVal = window.__env.url+ "Preview/TypeDefinition";
    var xslSettingVal = $('#PreviewXml').val().replace(/\n/g, "");
    var allData = {
        'ObjectName': passThatVar,
        'DisplayDefinition': setting,
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: urlVal,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(allData),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
}
```

Button HTML:

```
<button onclick="saveSetting()"> Save Setting </button>
```

Comment: You should save them somewhere, because the second function is on click event.

Comment: Neither of your calls are synchronous (which is a good thing)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I meant Promises, I should reword the title haha.

Comment: Maybe in the DOM, add as an attribute the value you receive from the `GET` function to the `<button>`. Then when you hit the `<button>` and trigger the `POST` function, you can get the value from the `<button>` DOM's attribute itself.

Comment: For whoever voted down the question, you need to specify why you've down voted it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Your button:

```
<button id="save-settings"> Save Setting </button>
```

After your get request, set a data-attribute to your button:

```
function firstCallBack() {
    $.get('http://website.com/API/docs/v1').then(function(data1){
        $("#save-settings").data("passMe", "PassMeToPOST");
    }).then(function (data2) {              
    })
}
```

Bind the click event(its a best practice than using inline events):

```
$("#save-settings").on("click", saveSetting);
```

On your `saveSetting()` function:

```
function saveSetting() {
    var allData = {
        'ObjectName': $(this).data("passMe"),
        'DisplayDefinition': setting,
    }
    //... your post request 
}
```

You can also check if the get request has finished before starting the post request(to avoid a bug in an extreme scenario):

```
if (!$(this).data("passMe")) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: The data in "objectName" doesn't seems like its being pass, where do you use the `if` condition?

Comment: @nCore The if should be in very beggining of your function, in order cancels it. Well, I don't know whats happening, but it should work.

Comment: Yeah its working fine now, its just my `get` request takes time to finish. I'm using angular2 and the browser-sync checks every file for changes, so if I reload my page it re-run the script which sucks.

Answer (score -1):

You're basically asking how to keep a variable out of the global scope. This is called encapsulation. It is a good instinct but a large topic. Here is a post that I like on the topic: http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/

One low budget way of doing this is instead of making a global variable for your value, make a global namespace for your own use.

```
var MyUniquelyNamedThing = {};
...
// get response:
MyUniquelyNamedThing.ThatValueINeed = data;
...
// posting:
data = { val1: MyUniquelyNamedThing.ThatValueINeed , etc. };
```